# sudo: unable to resolve host Mapi

Tags: sudo, hostname

When I enter `sudo su`, I get following error message:

```
pi@Mapi ~ $ sudo su
sudo: unable to resolve host Mapi
```

So in the `/etc/hosts/` and in the `/etc/hostname` the hostname Mapi is exact the thame (I also check that there is no space)

```
pi@Mapi ~ $ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost localhost.localdomain
::1             localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0         ip6-localnet
ff00::0         ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ip6-allnodes
ff02::2         ip6-allrouters
127.0.1.1       Mapi

pi@Mapi ~ $ cat /etc/hostname
Mapi
```

---

there are no spaces:

[/ets/hosts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQ3O9.png)
[/etc/hostnam](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iEh3.png)

Comment: Please try to edit these files with `nano` - `sudo nano /etc/hostname`; `sudo nano /etc/hosts` - and if there are some green or red colored spaces just remove them. If you have edited these files with a not appropriate text editor, it can be a cause of this problem. If this is true, If I were you I would rewrite the content of these files entirely in `nano`.

Comment: Rather than a screenshot of text, please copy-paste the contents of those files directly into your question as an [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/851930/edit) instead of as an answer.  Please also try not to use screenshots for text, it makes it harder for some of us to read due to screen space being at a premium.

Comment: The content of the screenshot is included in the question?!? I uploaded the screenshot to make it clear that there are no spaces